# How do I slide out the previous fragment only 50% or 25% without being graphically cut?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, slide

To replace a fragment with another one I'm using `setCustomAnimations()` with the following slide in enter resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0"/>
</set>
```

and the following slide out exit resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="-50%p"/>
</set>
```

However, this does not work as expected. The fragment exitting the screen plays its 50% translation animation, but the fragment going in doesn't move 100%, it moves 50% along with the fragment going out, then jumps to 100% at the end of the animation.

If I make both displacements 100% the animation works fine, but I want to make the slide out fragment only 50% to emulate the same visual effect when you start an activity and the activity slide in full but only 50% of the previous activity slides out.

Is there another way to make the new fragment sliding in to show up *above* the fragment sliding out, so their animations don't conflict with each other?

Answer (score 0):

The slide in/out animation is playing correctly, but Android has a hard time figuring out what fragment should be drawn on top of the other. In this particular case, the fragment being slid out is still rendered on top of the one coming in, and hence the new fragment is only fully visible when the whole animation finishes.

To address this, it is possible to override this method in the Fragment to alter the elevation when the animation is being played:

```
override fun onCreateAnimation(transit: Int, enter: Boolean, nextAnim: Int): Animation? {
    when (nextAnim) {
        R.anim.slide_out_left -> {
            view?.elevation = -10f
        }
        R.anim.slide_in_left -> {
            view?.elevation = -10f
        }
        else -> discard()
    }
    return super.onCreateAnimation(transit, enter, nextAnim)
}
```

That will make the *old* fragment be drawn *below* the new one, and there will be no graphical glitches.

The `onCreateAnimation()` method is also a good place to darken the fragment a little bit, which helps differentiate it visually from the new fragment despite both having the same color.